# How to copy values from one array of objects to another array of objects in typescript, angular 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an Angular component that needs an array of objects!  I wrote the code for fetching the array in a service:

```
    private roles_list = [];

    getRoles(): any[]  {
        return this.roles_list;
             }

    roles(){

    const promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            return this._http.get('/api/getData')
                .subscribe(data => {
                    //this.roles_list = data
                    for (var i=0 ; i < Object.keys(data).length ; i++){
                        var temp = {};
                        temp["role"] = "role";
                        temp["value"] = data[i].key;
                        this.roles_list.push(temp);
                    }

                    console.log("data");
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("roles_list");
                    console.log(this.roles_list);
                    resolve(this.roles_list);
                },
                err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    return promise;
}
```

I'm then resolving the promise in a component:

```
private roles = [];
this.getDataService.roles().then(res => {
      console.log(typeof(res));

       this.roles =  res.map(o => {
          return {name: o.name,role: o.role}
      });
  });
```

However this is throwing various errors, it says "the map method is not available for {}" although res should be an array not an object? any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I solved the problem by sending a JSON object through resolve() and then doing the processing on the component's ngInit(), does anybody know why this problem occured? can we only send object's through resolve ?

Comment: What does actually `console.log(typeof(res))`  logs? And why are you wrapping your `Observable` inside a `Promise` when you could actually just return the `Observable`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `console.log(typeof(res))`  logs `object` shouldn't this give something like array? I didn't get your point about Observable ? I haven't used an observable in this code !

Comment: The '_http' instance you injected in your service uses `Observables` under the hood, that's why you can actually call the method `subscribe` on it, cause every method (`get`, `post`, etc...) returns an `Observable` of type `Response`.

Comment: btw, are you using `HttpModule` or `HttpClientModule`?

Comment: I'm using HttpClientModule although HttpModule is also included in my app.

Comment: @OsmanCea the problem was with the promise, we can only pass a single object through a promise, for a collection of objects and observable should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private roles = [];
this.getDataService.roles().then(res => {
    console.log(typeof(res));

    for(let r of res){
        this.roles.push({name: r.name,role: r.role})
    }

});
```

Comment: It says "Type '{}' is not an array type or a string type.", it's considering res as an object although it should consider it as an array of objects!

Comment: any idea why that could be?

Comment: Could you please show what shows `console.log(res);` ?

Comment: It gives object

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, apparently a promise can only pass a single object through it's resolve method. Hence when I pass an array of objects through it, it considers it just an object, and obviously, an object can not be assigned to an array of objects.
The way to do it was to create an observable in the service and subscribe to it in the component.